# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc43' in position 1: surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, character-encoding, surrogate-pairs

I have a list containing `placenames` and I want to create another array, initially empty, and then iterate the list of `placenames` and fill up my empty array with these `placenames`.

For example, my first location is `'CHARTRIDGE'` and accessing this element in my `LOCARY` list via `LOCARY[S[0][0]]` I get: `'CHARTRIDGE'`

I created an empty array: `LOCLIST = np.empty([len(LOCARY),1])`

I then wrote a `for` loop to fill it up with the items from `LOCARY` using:

```
for i in range(len(LOCARY)):
    LOCLIST[i] = LOCARY[S[i][0]]
```

But I get the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc43' in position 1: surrogates not allowed

I'm wondering if it doesn't like the characters `'` in the `placename`.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried encoding and stripping the string like in this example?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: The string `'CHARTRIDGE'` is plain ASCII, there's no `'\udc43'` there. I suspect that there's something wrong with the way you're reading your data, or the data itself is corrupt. It's hard to say without a [mcve]. FWIW,  `'\udc43'` is a ["low surrogate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates). As the link mentions, surrogates are used in UCS and they _must_ occur in pairs.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've just given it a look and its gone above my head I'm afraid. I'm new to python, been stuck on this for a few hours today.

Comment: In an effort to help, could you post the contents of the `LOCARY`?  Could you also include some more of the stack trace?  Maybe anything that says where in your program's execution the error was thrown?

Comment: Hi there, yes LOCARY has the output
array(['CHARTRIDGE', 'PIDDINGTON ROAD', 'WOODLANDS', ..., 'TONTINE FARM',
       'NICKLE COTTAGES', 'WADE FARM'],
      dtype='<U40')